# reverse the lower part of the chart HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I write 'reversed' for yAxis: `reversed: true`

yAxis [inverted](http://regexinfo.ru/charts/chart_good_scale1.php)

but the lower part of the chart is not reversed: [ScreenShot](http://regexinfo.ru/charts/not_reversed.JPG)

please, tell me how reverse the lower part of the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify settings for the **[`navigator.yAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.yAxis)** explicitly,

```
navigator: {
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true
    }
}
```

**[Reverse navigator y axis too | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/sUDFE/)**

I strongly recommend going through the [api reference of highstock](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock) and its [demo site](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/), they have some great documentation and live and running example codes, you should be able to solve most of the simple use cases from these

Comment: ok, thanks! I used to search for the word "reversed" on http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts, but the result was only: legend.reversed, xAxis.reversed and yAxis.reversed. navigator.yAxis.reversed not found

Comment: You'll get a hang of how the documentation is to be interpreted or searched in a few weeks. @I.Zaytsev navigator has a yAxis and it says all options of yAxis apply. All you need to know is that navigator exists or it is called `navigator` and then just look at what all are the options are available